# Redirecionar qualquer subdominio para meu servidor

Tags: dns, subdomínio, domínio

Registrei um domínio no [registro.br](https://registro.br/) e tenho um servidor na king host.

Na minha aplicação, quando o usuário cria um conta, ele é redirecionado para uma página com seu nome no subdominio. Exemplo:

- Domínio: **exemplo.com.br**
- Usuário **joao** se cadastra
- O usuário é redirecionado para **joao.exemplo.com.br**

Porém o dns não funciona para esse subdomínio.

Minha primeira ideia foi criar um CNAME com *.exemplo.com.br apontando pro ip do servidor, mas o registro br não aceita wildcards na configuração do dns.

A kinghost tem um painel para gerenciamento de domínios. Lá consegui adicionar o cname *.exemplo.com.br, mas não resolveu.

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso funcionar?

Comment: Para fazer isso, acredito que você vai precisar alugar um servidor em que possa configurar como DNS e registrar esses subdomínios lá para fazer a resolução de nomes. Isso envolve várias questões de segurança, por isso um host comum vai ser obviamente travado. Veja se o seu host tem algum servidor que te dê essa opção.

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de usar os DNS do Registro.br, tem que apontar os DNS para os NameServers do seu hosting, normalmente `ns1.nomedohosting.net`:

<kbd>[image: print do registro.br]</kbd>

E no seu painel, p.ex. cPanel, adicionar o registro wildcard:
<kbd>[image]</kbd>